# Loop text file and grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to loop each row in a textfile input.csv and search that row with grep in file.txt. And then output to output.csv. But I don't get this code to work:

```
while read NAME
do
grep -F "$NAME" file.txt >> output.csv
done < input.csv
```

The input.csv looks like this:

```
search1
search2
search3
```

Comment: probably `grep -f patterns file` may be best. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Check there are no hidden characters you are not expecting in the files .

Answer (score 1):

The `while read` loop isn't necessary, `grep` alone can do it:

```
grep -F -f input.csv file.txt > output.csv
```